# why does the system call socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW) return a file descriptor of -1 ? I believe this is an error

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I'm writing a program in c++ to write to a raw socket created by the linux kernel. As I understand it, the way to create a socket in user-space is by invoking the system call:

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
```

. But, for some reason the file descriptor returned by this function is always -1. If I specify the socket type as SOCK_STREAM, however, this doesn't seem to occur. Some insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try looking at the value of `errno`?

Comment: @R: My money is on `EPERM`. (Edit: Whoops meant `EACCESS`)

Comment: @Galik If you do that you lose the value returned by `socket()` so you can't use it for anything. You can't even close it. So you will have at best a resource leak..

Answer (score 3):

Your process has to be privileged in order to open raw sockets. Test running it through `sudo`.

In general, you should check error codes when this sort of thing happens; if you had, you'd see that `errno` is set to `EACCESS` by the failing `socket` call, telling you everything you need to know about *why* the call failed.